# How to prevent autoRotation in a view controller embedded in a navigation controller?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode-storyboard

I have a view controller embedded in a navigation controller like so:

[image]

The navigation Controller is a custom subclass I shown below

```
 class SNNAvigationViewController: UINavigationController {

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        }

        override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
            super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
            // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
        }

        override var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
            return false
        }



    }
```

As you can see I override shouldAutorotate to say false. Also in the Camera view controller I have:

```
class CameraViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate, CameraButtonDelegate {
...
    override var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
        return false
    }
...
}
```

However no luck, when I turn the phone, the view still auto-rotates. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add this code in the navigationcontroller?

```
override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return .portrait
}
```

(If you want the portrait naturally).

Comment: that goes in the navigation controller custom subclass right? still auto-rotates with that in there :(

Comment: Can you add a breakpoint in the shouldautorotate method and see the stack?